# Flash plugin not detected by Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash, centos-7, plugins

I am using CentOS 7 and Firefox 68. I installed the Flash plugin using the `yum install flash-plugin` command. All seems well, the `.so` files are installed and in `/usr/lib64/flash-plugin` and softlinked from `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`.

However, Firefox does not seem to detect the plugin when checking `about:plugins`. Is there some setting I am missing here?

Comment: Try in `about:config` to set `dom.ipc.plugins.sandbox-level.flash` to 0 and restart Firefox.

Comment: @harrymc I do not have that config setting. I tried some others that looked like it, but nothing made a change.

Comment: It exists on my Firefox version 72 (Windows).

Comment: Goto the download page with Firefox and install it from within Firefox http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer